# Array.sort().filter(...) with zero in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Why 0 is not returned by the following filter ?

```
[0, 5, 4].sort().filter(function(i){return i}) // returns : [4, 5]
```

Comment: What exactly were you hoping to filter?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`0` is considered a falsy value.

Your filter function is essentially returning `false` for `0` and filtering it from the array.

Check [this](http://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/) out for a deeper look.

Answer (score 13):

`.filter()` function by default excludes **falsy items** from filtered output.

```
// ----- falsy items in JS --------
false 
null 
undefined
0 
NaN
'' //Empty string
```

> **Solution :**

If you still want to keep them, just remember this short tip :

---

### Return `true` to keep the element, `false` otherwise.

**Example :**

```
[0, 5, 4].sort().filter(function(i){
return true // returning true to keep i element
});
```

Answer (score 8):

filter is to check for a condition. You are returning the value itself, which is not a correct usage.
For this it should be

```
[0, 5, 4].sort().filter(function(i){return true;}); //[0,4,5] is returned
```

when you pass values itself, all non-zeros numbers equal to truthy and 0 equals falsy value and so it is ignored by filter. If you still want to stick to this way, due to some reason, enclose 0 within quotes and that will solve the problem.

```
[0, 5, 4].sort().filter(function(i){return i==0?'0':i;}) //[0,4,5] is returned
```

Answer (score 7):

To keep **0**, but still filter out **falsy** values, try this:

```
[0, 5, undefined, 4, null, 7, NaN, -4].sort().filter(function(item){
  return item || item === 0;
});
```

**Edit:** Refactored with ES2015 arrow function

```
[0, 5, undefined, 4, null, 7, NaN, -4].sort().filter(item => item || item === 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
[0, 5, 4].sort().filter(function(i){
    return ((i) ? i : !i);
})
```

Comment: isn't this equal to return true :P